# Java. Get/Set returns null

Tags: java, get, null, set

first post and first question.

I am a java beginner so I apologise in advance if my question is very basic, but I have tried for 2 days to find the answer on Internet and on StackOverFlow without success

What I am trying to do: I want to "set" the value of a variable, and then "get" it back multiple other times.

What is happening: the first time that I "get" it, it (correctly) returns the value that I initialized. the following times it returns "null"

Here the code
1) Main class

```
public class Provasetgetaltraclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        set_e_get_1 set_e_get_1Obj = new set_e_get_1();         
        set_e_get_1Obj.execute_var_to_set_e_get1();
        set_e_get_1Obj.execute_var_to_set_e_get2();
    }    
}
```

2) class with the actions

```
public class set_e_get_1 {

    public void execute_var_to_set_e_get1(){
        var_to_set_e_get var_to_set_e_getObj = new var_to_set_e_get(); 
        var_to_set_e_getObj.setname("test"); 
        System.out.println(var_to_set_e_getObj.getname());
    }

    public void execute_var_to_set_e_get2(){
        var_to_set_e_get var_to_set_e_getObj = new var_to_set_e_get(); 
        System.out.println(var_to_set_e_getObj.getname());
    }
}
```

3) class with the variable and the set and get methods

```
public class var_to_set_e_get {
    private String name; 

    public void setname (String new_name){
        name = new_name; 
    }

    public String getname (){
        return name; 
    }
}
```

4) the result, when I run the main, is

```
test
null
```

(what I would like is test and test)

I don't want to store the variable in a database or a file unless necessary, as I'd like to have this working on the fly

If you can help me I'd really appreciate it
Many thanks

Comment: Wow, you don't seem to have read the Java naming conventions, do you? :)

Comment: As @kocko mentioned it's really hard to follow your code without sticking to the standard Java name conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that in each call of the methods `execute_var_to_set_e_get1` and `execute_var_to_set_e_get2` you are creating different objects.

In the first one you are setting `name` to a `String`, but in the last, you are not doing that.

So, it will be `null` (by default).

**Note:** The behavior that you have described is of a `static` attribute. If you declase `name` as `static`, it will be shared between all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your two methods `execute_var_to_set_e_get1` and `execute_var_to_set_e_get2` each create a different object of `var_to_set_e_get` class. You set the value of the property only in one of them, so of course it will be null in the other.

If you want the value you stored in the first object to be available in the second method, your first method has to return the object it creates, and the second method should accept that object :

```
public var_to_set_e_get execute_var_to_set_e_get1(){
    var_to_set_e_get var_to_set_e_getObj = new var_to_set_e_get(); 
    var_to_set_e_getObj.setname("test"); 
    System.out.println(var_to_set_e_getObj.getname());
    return var_to_set_e_getObj;
}

public void execute_var_to_set_e_get2(var_to_set_e_get var_to_set_e_getObj){ 
    System.out.println(var_to_set_e_getObj.getname());
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    set_e_get_1 obj = new set_e_get_1();         
    var_to_set_e_get v = obj.execute_var_to_set_e_get1();
    obj.execute_var_to_set_e_get2(v);
}
```